# Unix: find directory filenames listed in a text file and move to new directory

Tags: find, osx

I'm a command line novice trying to figure out the appropriate command to execute the following within the Terminal in Mac OS X.

Assuming I've placed all files in the same directory, I want to isolate and move a selected set of directory files listed in a text file to a new directory, how do I:

- read the selected list of filenames listed in a .txt file
- find all matches by filename
- isolate and move all file matches to a new directory

I've found this command to find (either or both) a filestring.filetype in a current directory and move all matches to a new directory:

```
find . -type f -iname "filestring.filetype" -print0 |
  xargs -0 -J % mv % ~/NewDirectory/
```

And I've found this `tar` command however it creates an archive copy of each filename listed in `filename.txt`

```
tar -cf - -T filename.txt | (cd /path/to/new/dir && tar -xvf -)
```

Any help is much appreciated!

The following solution was provided by a trusted source:

```
cat "filename.txt" | xargs -I % mv % ~/NewDirectory/
```

Comment: Did any of those commands accomplish what you wanted?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. The tar command is closest however it creates an archive copy of the files listed in the filename and leaves the original directory files untouched.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this. Works with bash.

```
while read file
do
    mv -v -i "$file" ~/NewDirectory/
done < listoffiles.txt
```

Comment: Thank-you however this doesn't seem to execute in the Terminal

Comment: I have bash 3.2 installed, doesn't seem work.  Any other ideas?

Comment: You sure you typed it in correctly? I don't have access to any system with bash 3.2, but it also works in a busybox shell... -- also what's doesn't seem to work mean exactly? Error message?

Comment: Thanks for getting back.  I typed it letter-for-letter in the Terminal.  I type each line, hit enter after each, after the last line, nothing happens as if the command isn't initiated.

Comment: That'd happen if the listoffiles.txt is empty. You could run it in a `bash -x` shell (debug output). Even if the file is empty it should show a `+ read file` at the very least... otherwise I'm out of ideas, sorry.

Comment: Do spaces in the filename create an issue?

Comment: if your listoffiles.txt has a space you use `"list of files.txt"`. Otherwise only newlines in the filename would create an issue as your list could no longer be one file per line.

Comment: Yep - i'm talking about spaces in each filename in the list of filenames listed within "listoffiles.txt"  One line per filename as well so that shouldn't be the issue...

Answer (score 0):

The `find ... xargs` solution you suggested works for me using `Bash version 3.2.48(1)-release` on Mac OS X 10.6.8.

```
mkdir -v -p ~/NewDirectory
find . -type f -maxdepth 1 -iname "*.pdf" -print0 |
   xargs -0 -J % mv -i -v % ~/NewDirectory
```

If you are going to use a text file containing the full paths of the files to be moved, make sure that each file path stored in the text file is terminated by a null byte. This way even newline characters in your file paths will not be of concern to you in the future.

```
# some tests
mkdir -v -p ~/NewDirectory
find "${PWD}" -type f -maxdepth 1 -print0 > listoffiles.txt
xargs -0 -n 1 ls -l <listoffiles.txt
# use a grep regex filter on file paths
grep -az 'bash' listoffiles.txt | xargs -0 -n 1 ls -l  
xargs -0 -n 1 sh -c 'echo mv -v -i "$1" ~/NewDirectory' _ <listoffiles.txt
xargs -0 -J % ls -ld % ~/NewDirectory <listoffiles.txt
xargs -0 -J % mv -i -v % ~/NewDirectory <listoffiles.txt
```

To debug your code in `Bash` use:

```
#help set
set -Eeuxv -o pipefail +H   # for debugging
trap 'printf "%s\n" "$?"; trap - EXIT' EXIT HUP INT QUIT PIPE TERM ERR
```